# ActiveRecord custom has_many association makes multiple calls to the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a pair of ActiveRecord objects that have a belongs_to ... has_many association, with the has_many association being custom-made. Example:

First AR object:

```
class Car < Vehicle
    has_many :wheels, class_name: "RoundObject", foreign_key: :vehicle_id, conditions: "working = 1"

    validates_presence_of :wheels
    ...
end
```

Second AR object:

```
class RoundObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :vehicle
    ...
end
```

Please note that the above is not indicative of my app's function, simply to outline the association between my two AR objects.

The issue I'm having is that, when I reset the cache (and thus my Rails app re-caches all AR objects in the database), when it comes time for the `RoundObject` object to get re-cached, it makes multiple calls to the database, one for each unique `vehicle_id` associated with the collection of `RoundObject`s. The SQL commands being run are output to the console, so this is what my output looked like:

```
  RoundObject Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `round_objects`.* FROM `round_objects` WHERE `round_objects`.`vehicle_id` = 28 AND (active = 1)
  RoundObject Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `round_objects`.* FROM `round_objects` WHERE `round_objects`.`vehicle_id` = 29 AND (active = 1)
  RoundObject Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `round_objects`.* FROM `round_objects` WHERE `round_objects`.`vehicle_id` = 30 AND (active = 1)
```

My app has several other AR objects that use the built-in `has_many` association without any modifications, and I notice that they only hit the database once when resetting the cache. For instance:

```
Micropost Load (15.0ms)  SELECT `microposts`.* FROM `microposts` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`id` = `microposts`.`post_id` WHERE `microposts`.`active` = 1 AND `posts`.`active` = 1
```

My question is, how can I make my AR object only hit the database once on cache reset, while still maintaining the custom `has_many` association I need? Can I manually force a join on the SQL query being called, and will this help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use includes method while calling your Vehicle object to include the RoundObject.
It will go like this:

```
Vehicle.where(conditions_for_getting_data).includes(:round_object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why using a custom `has_many` definition might cause this behavior to happen?

Comment: @Argus9 the issue is not unique to custom :has_many associations. It is called the N+1 Queries Problem, and it can affect any :has_many association. You can avoid N+1 queries by careful usage of `includes` to "eager-load" a has many association with a single query, rather than individual queries. You should read about `includes` in the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)